# apex:actionsupport event not firing

Tags: visualforce, actionfunction, datatable, actionsupport

I have this sample page created that uses Jquery datatable within that I'm using `<apex:actionsupport>`  and when I click on the hyperlink for that particular column it does not fire the event and the way I'm testing is that when the user clicks on the `a href` it fires the action method on the controller and I'm spitting the `system.debug` just to make sure it does calling this method. When I looked at the log it does not show that action method fires, what I'm doing wrong here?

**Markup:**

```
 <apex:form id="myform"> 
        <head>
            <apex:includescript value="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" / >
                <apex:includescript value="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" />
                <apex:stylesheet value="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />
                <script>
                j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
                j$(document).ready( function () {
                    var tbl = j$('[id$="tbl"]').DataTable({
                        //for empty
                        "columnDefs": [{
                            "defaultContent": "empty",
                            "targets": "_all"
                        }]
                    });
                });
                </script>
            </head>

<table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="tbl" >
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <apex:repeat value="{!myData}" var="t" id="reg">
                        <tr>
                            <td>  
                                <apex:actionsupport action="{!loadDataById}" event="onclick" rerender="pb2" >  
                                <a href="#"><apex:param name="selectedId" value="{!t.Id}">{!t.Name}</apex:param></a>
                                </apex:actionsupport>  
                            </td>
                            <td>{!t.description} </td> 
                        </tr> 
                    </apex:repeat>
                </tbody>
            </table> 

          <br/>
          <apex:pageblock id="pb2 ...>
             {!SecondList}
          </apex:pageblock>

 </apex:form>
```

**Controller:**

```
public List<my_custom_object> secondList { get; set; } 
public void loadDataById()
{
    String selectedId = System.currentPagereference().getParameters().get('selectedId');
    List<my_custom_object>  myDataList = [SELECT ...];
    system.debug('selectedid: ' + selectedId);
    secondList = myDataList ; 
}
```

Comment: Can you try with `apex:outputLink` instead of plain `a` tag? See if it works..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to nest the `<apex:actionSupport>` tag *within* the tag whose action you are trying to support. You have it inverted.

**Correct**

```
<a ...>
    <apex:actionSupport ... />
</a>
```

**Incorrect**

```
<apex:actionSupport ...>
    <a ...>
    </a>
</apex:actionSupport>
```

---

However, it appears you may want to simply use the **[`<apex:commandLink>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_commandLink.htm)** tag here...

**Joy**

```
<td>
    <apex:commandLink action="{!loadDataById}" rerender="pb2">
        <apex:param name="selectedId" value="{!t.Id}" />
        {!t.Name}
    </apex:commandLink>
</td>
```

**No Joy**

```
<td>
    <apex:actionSupport ... />
    <a ...>
        <apex:param ...>
    </a>
</td>
```

---

Or if you are really committed to sticking with an `<a>` tag for some reason, at least follow the approach outlined in the documentation on [`<apex:actionSupport>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionSupport.htm), adapted below to closer mirror your situation. Basically you want to add the click listener to a wrapper div.

```
<apex:page controller="Throwaway">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:outputpanel id="counter">
            <a href="#">Click Me!: {!count}</a>
            <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!incrementCounter}" rerender="counter"/>
        </apex:outputpanel>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Adrian, did not help either so when I click on the hyperlink it does not fire the event and i do not see any activity in the logs.

Comment: I did not know that we can use `actionSupport` for plain HTML elements, I thought only for `apex` namespace elements.

Comment: `Joy` snippet worked! 1+